# Is $\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)^{o} = \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^{o}$?

Tags: general-topology

$A^{o}$ is the set of all interior points. The definition of an interior point is as follows: Let $A$ be a set of real numbers. A point $p\in A$ is an interior point if and only if $p$ belongs to some open interval $S_p$ which is contained in $A$.

Claim: $\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)^{o} = \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^{o}$

proof: Let $A_i = (-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i})$ Then $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i = \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. So, $$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)^{o} = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$$ $A_i^{o} = (-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i})$ then $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^{o} = \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ Therefore, $$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)^{o} = \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^{o}$$

I am not sure if this is right, and I feel like I could use a similar argument to prove that it does not equal, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Note: I made a mistake in an earlier post it wasn't suppose to be unions but intersections, sorry about that.

Comment: I think that  $\big( \cap_{i=1}^ \infty A_i \big) ^° \neq \{ 0\}$ , it is $\phi$ ( of course if you are working in real numbers wit standard topology) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: sets of interior points are always open.

*Open* sets $A_i$ can be found such that $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ (a countable intersection of open sets) is *not* open. Realize that $A_i^o=A_i$ here. Then the equality mentioned in your question cannot be true. This because LHS is an open set and RHS is not.

You are giving an example yourself: $A_i=(-\frac1{i},\frac1{i})$. Here $A_i=A_i^o$ and the intersection of these sets is $\{0\}$. However $\{0\}^o=\varnothing\neq\{0\}$.